# Video starts lagging no matter the format - RAM usage error?

Tags: windows-10, memory, video, lag

I’m having trouble with any form of video playback on my machine no matter if it’s played with VLC or HTML5 webvideo (Youtube) via Firefox or Edge. The preview video in Adobe Premiere is also affected.

In all cases the video starts lagging (picture and sound) after a while of opening and playing several different videos or after working some time in Premiere. I thought I had narrowed the problem down to a RAM issue but apparently, I was a victim of spurious correlation:

My machine had 16 GB RAM and the video started lagging whenever RAM usage was approaching 8 GB or RAM. I figured that the RAM was defective and although tests did not confirm this I changed all RAM blocks and increased RAM to 32 GB. However, the problem persists. Whenever task manager shows 10-11 GB of RAM usage videos start lagging. As soon as the RAM usage drops bellow these values video playback is back to normal.

I have also kept an eye on video memory. But this does not seem to be an issue as the video starts lagging no matter if video memory is used by 10 or 90%.

I am really at a loss of ideas what else I should try or check. Any suggestions?

System information:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- RAM: 32 GB (4 x 8 GB DDR3-1600 Crucial Ballistix) [CPU-Z Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7gkT.png)
- HD: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500 GB
- CPU: Core i5 4570S [CPU-Z CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQVXc.png)
- Mainboard: Intel DH87RL (newest BIOS 07/20/2015)
- Graphics: Intel HD 4600 (1024 MB of reserved memory)

Comment: In VLC did you try to increase the buffering?

Comment: I'd be tempted to say you need a dedicated graphics card; but I can't back that up with anything other then anecdotal evidence. I fixed my playback issues with some fairly low budget cards, a GT210 in one machine & a much better GT1030 in the other. [both fanless, specifically, to keep the noise down]

Comment: @cybernard: yes, to no effect

Comment: @Tetsujin: this would probably be my next guess. The reason I am hesitating is that this is a recent issue. I am using this machine since 2014 and the problem is occurring for only about 5 months.

Comment: 3 years ago you were watching smaller videos? Again, purely anecdotal but I've found as time goes by, I want to see higher & higher spec content, as the tech advances to allow me to.

Comment: That is true. But what about the video I watched 5 months ago when everything was still working fine? Sems to be very sudden to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite some time and many tries, I was able to identify the error in my Bluetooth audio setup. I was using a Bluetooth 4 dongle and a Sony Bluetooth headset. If the error occurs it was gone as soon as I disconnected and the reconnected my headset .The error never occurs when I was using a direct connected (non Bluetooth) setup.
I post this answer in the hope that people with the same issue have an additional thing to try out.

Comment: Although I cannot verify the solution, you have my upvote for sharing it with the community.